# Whats the best way to exclude burried dependencies in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Say, for example, you see this in your dependencies for a Gradle project:

```
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core: -> 3.2.7.RELEASE
     +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
     +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.13.RELEASE -> 4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.13.RELEASE -> 4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.13.RELEASE -> 4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.13.RELEASE -> 4.1.7.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.13.RELEASE -> 4.1.7.RELEASE (*)
```

Is it possible to exclude `org.springframework:spring-expression` without first excluding `org.springframework:spring-context` from `org.springframework.security:spring-security-core`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend adding this to your Gradle build, perhaps:

```
dependencies {
  // Explicitly include spring-expression transitive dependency then manage its dependencies
  compile('org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.13.RELEASE') {
    transitive = false
  }
}
```

You can also force specific transitive dependencies [See Section 52.4.2. Client module dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) of the Gradle User Guide

Comment: Do this for every single dependency? What's the point of a dependency system, then? We are looking at around 500 dependencies here. I must admit I'm tempted to write a script that does exactly that though.

Comment: I've been trying to untie this Gordian Knot for a week now and this is only one of the sub-projects.

Comment: This is the answer (i.e. the best that can be done) but I find it disappointing as I feel it says some pretty negative things about the maturity of Gradle. In a nutshell, you are stuck eliminating the dependency system rather than using it to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In order to exclude a dependency from any configuration use:

```
 configurations {
   all {
     exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-expression'
   }
 }
```

If want to enforce a specific version of dependency you can use:

```
 configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
     if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework') {
       details.useVersion '3.2.13.RELEASE'
     }
   }
 }
```

This may help if a transitive dependency gets pulled multiple times with different versions.

Comment: I don't want to exclude it from a configuration. I want to exclude it from a dependency. Problem is that I do need the library in question but I've got too many copies of it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the above will exclude it from everything everywhere that uses that configuration, right? All of them in this case. That would be a problem in other sub-projects as well as this one since the library is used.

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude it from dependency"? At the end you allways have at flat path for a configuration (compile, runtime, ...). You can remove dependencies from one or multiple configurations. Or do you have different versions of the same lib and want to enforce one specific version?

Comment: What I have is a build that was generated by init on a really big project with lots of interdependencies and quite a few duplicates. I'm doing dependency management through the Spring plugin, so versions are not at issue. I don't see a configuration block here in this sub project, BTW.  Just dependencies, compile, exclude and testCompile. I do see the war plugin.

Comment: If versions are not an issue why do you get duplicates? With "duplicate" I aussume you mean the same jar in different versions , don't you? If there's no configuration section you can simply add it, either in `allprojects { ...}` or a specific project or even in `configure(rootProject) { ... }`.

Comment: Re: Duplicates It's because Maven handles these and Gradle doesn't so when you migrate over you get stuck with a bunch of em.